# How does an embedded rocksdb written in C++ work by including the lib/JAR in java?

Tags: java, rocksdb

Rocksdb is written in c++, and yet by me simply adding the java jar to my project I am able to use it.

How does this work under the jvm?

Comment: The code is available to review - https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/tree/main/java/src/main/java/org/rocksdb

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [_Java Native Interface_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jni/index.html)? It allows Java code to interact with native code. Looking at the source code linked above, the library abstracts this away for you.

Comment: Several .so/.dll/… files precompiled for various common OSs and architectures are included in the RocksDB JARs. The actual magic that loads them is [here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/dab19afe564801a31024461fa7a8e4251b857f23/java/src/main/java/org/rocksdb/NativeLibraryLoader.java#L54).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something called JNI to call c++ code from java programs. The compiled c++ code is part of the jar alongside the java code [that does the heavy lifting] that the developer interacts with